# Values not displaying in Visuals

Tags: powerbi

Has anyone come across an issue where their values do not display? instead an icon appears.
I have created line graphs and the values show sometimes, other times the PowerBI icon shows, I think it might be something to do with the size of the visual? [This is what is displayed instead of a line graph] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnyQL.png)

I have tried resizing the graphic but still receive the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is when a responsive visual is too small. You mentioned that resizing the visual didn't work, how big did you try?

Anyways, for a visual, you can try switching off `Responsive`. Select the visual, then go to `Format visual` > `General` > `Properties` > `Advanced options`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did not resize it enough. The issue is the data could contain a lot of information which I did not account for. After resizing considerably the visuals are working now.